# Array has at least 1 item - Dust.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I'm looking for a clever way in dust.js to determine if an array of objects (let's say items) has at least one item preferably without using @if or looping through every item

It would be nice if this worked, but it doesn't :(

```
{@size key=items}
    {@gt value=0}
        asdf
    {/gt}
{/size}
```

Comment: It's actually an empty object, not an array but still having the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/issues/47) with the same requirement. Typically you should create an alternative helper which should accept inner blocks, and this helper will internally call `@size` helper.

Let's name it `@sizeOf`:

```
dust.helpers.sizeOf = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var value = this.size(chunk, context, bodies, params);
  return (bodies && bodies.block) ? chunk.render(bodies.block, context.push({ isSelect: true, isResolved: false, selectKey: value })) : value;
};
```

And we should use it like this:

```
{@sizeOf key=items}
  {@gt value=0}
    asdf
  {/gt}
{/size}
```

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't think of a dust helper. I ended up using explicit arrays at the data level so I can use the simple {?data}{/data} check

Answer (score 1):

Assuming items is an empty array, this should work:

```
{?items}
    {#items}
        ...
    {/items}    
{:else}
    There are no results
{/items}
```